# Source not found at setContentView ~ android programming

Tags: android, google-maps

I m new at android programming.I try to display simple Google map on android device (4.1.2).

I added all of the permissions and google api key on ActivityManifest.xml

this is activity_maps.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<fragment 
     android:id="@+id/map"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is MapsActivity.java

```
package com.example.androidmapsapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity {

GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
    //googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.maps, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}
```

}

log cat

```
09-26 17:09:51.476: E/Trace(26750): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-26 17:09:51.501: I/System.out(26750): Sending WAIT chunk
09-26 17:09:51.501: W/ActivityThread(26750): Application com.example.androidmapsapp is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
09-26 17:09:51.526: I/dalvikvm(26750): Debugger is active
09-26 17:09:51.716: I/System.out(26750): Debugger has connected
09-26 17:09:51.716: I/System.out(26750): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-26 17:09:51.916: I/System.out(26750): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-26 17:09:52.116: I/System.out(26750): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-26 17:09:52.316: I/System.out(26750): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-26 17:09:52.516: I/System.out(26750): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-26 17:09:52.716: I/System.out(26750): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-26 17:09:52.921: I/System.out(26750): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-26 17:09:53.121: I/System.out(26750): debugger has settled (1377)
09-26 17:09:54.416: D/dalvikvm(26750): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
09-26 17:11:15.291: E/Trace(27618): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-26 17:11:15.306: I/System.out(27618): Sending WAIT chunk
09-26 17:11:15.306: W/ActivityThread(27618): Application com.example.androidmapsapp is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
09-26 17:11:15.316: I/dalvikvm(27618): Debugger is active
09-26 17:11:15.506: I/System.out(27618): Debugger has connected
09-26 17:11:15.506: I/System.out(27618): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-26 17:11:15.706: I/System.out(27618): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-26 17:11:15.906: I/System.out(27618): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-26 17:11:16.106: I/System.out(27618): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-26 17:11:16.306: I/System.out(27618): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-26 17:11:16.511: I/System.out(27618): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-26 17:11:16.711: I/System.out(27618): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-26 17:11:16.911: I/System.out(27618): debugger has settled (1404)
09-26 17:11:18.246: D/dalvikvm(27618): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
09-26 17:11:23.271: D/dalvikvm(27618): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
09-26 17:11:23.271: D/dalvikvm(27618): GC_CONCURRENT freed 172K, 9% free 9639K/10503K, paused 22ms+4ms, total 56ms
09-26 17:11:23.276: W/CursorWrapperInner(27618): Cursor finalized without prior close()
```

While debugging "setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);" it gives Source not found!

Comment: Do you have a logcat?

Comment: Am afraid you cannot debug into setContentView method unless you have the android sources attached.

Comment: I added log cat.. Actuallay I try this example. http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Comment: Why do you want to step into setContentView? If there's a bug in that method, then you should open a ticket in AOSP

Comment: I don't want to step into setContentView. I debug step by step with f6. It stops at 'setContentView' line and says 'Source not found'. Its not passing next step.

Comment: While you should be able to skip over closed-source portions *somehow* that may not be the most efficient path - do you really need to interactively debug this?  What actual problem are your trying to solve?  Have you considered using log messages instead of the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is the fact that you activity extends `MapActivity` which was correct for Google Map API V1, but shouldn't be used for Google Maps API V2. what should be used is a simple `Activity` or a `FragmentActivity` depending on which platform you are targeting.

In you case just try to change  this line:

```
public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity {
```

to this:

```
public class MapsActivity extends Activity {
```

if you still having problems you can go over this blog post I wrote to integrate Google Maps API V2 in your application and see if this helps you:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: still same problem :/ Thank u, I will look that blog.